# XML XSD Validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

So I am have got down to 1 errors (see below) when trying to Validate XML against XSD could any please point me in the right direction?

Error - The end-tag for element type "track" must end with a '>' delimiter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ingestion xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ingestion.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <album>
    <consumer_release_date>2006-01-01</consumer_release_date>
    <main_genre>Alternative</main_genre>
    <main_subgenre>Boogie</main_subgenre>
    <language>IT</language>
    <name>Peace,Love,Death Metal</name>
    <release_format_type>EP</release_format_type>
    <total_discs>1</total_discs>
    <tracks>
      <track>
        <main_genre>Alternative</main_genre>
        <main_subgenre>Boogie</main_subgenre>
        <isrc_code>BB1231234567</isrc_code>
        <language>IT</language>
        <name>FlamesgoHigher</name>
        <track_version>trackversion</track_version>
    </tracks>
    <upc_code>1234567890136</upc_code>
  </album>
</ingestion>
```

Comment: You are never closing your `<track>` so presumably the validation tries to match up with the `</track_version>` part.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how would I close this track ?, this has totally baffled me

Comment: In general it is better to provide some more information in your topic like "XML/XSD validation failed with error" or something that describes the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can close the  using

```
<tracks>
  <track>
    <main_genre>Alternative</main_genre>
    <main_subgenre>Boogie</main_subgenre>
    <isrc_code>BB1231234567</isrc_code>
    <language>IT</language>
    <name>FlamesgoHigher</name>
    <track_version>trackversion</track_version>
   </track>
</tracks>
```

Comment: now I get -error 19:
15
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'track' is not complete. One of '{"":catalog_tier, "":sequence_number}' is expected

Comment: Possible cause: Some child elements `sequence_number` and  `catalog_tier` are missing.